# How can I compare myqueryresult and expectedresult?

Tags: c#

When I run myQuery in sqlPlus I am getting **"n"** result... How can I compare myqueryresult and expectedresult if they are same... and show hello message in C#.

```
using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(myQuery, conn1))
{
    string expectedresult = "n";
    string myqueryresult = crtCommand.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
    if (expectedresult == myqueryresult )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `crtCommand.ExecuteScalar()` method

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected, i think it is not what you expected.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I missed that part.